How to find the power function given exponential distribution?
Let $X$ be distributed according to $Exp(θ)$ and $H_0: θ = 1 $ and $ H_1: θ = 5$. We have a test that rejects the null hypothesis if $X < 0.05$. Determine the power of the test.
In the answers they did: $ h(5) = P(X < 0.05 \mid \theta = 5) = \int_0^{0} 0.055e^{-5x} \, dx = \left. -e^{-5x} \right|_0^{0.05} = 1 - e^{-5 \cdot 0.05} \approx 0.221.
 $
This is my attempt to interpret the solution, so since "power is the probability of rejecting it when the nyll hypothesis H0 is false" and in this case it is $X<0.05$. So by caclulating the probability of it we wil get the correct answer. But I am not entirely sure what they are doing in the integral at all. I feel like it is an error when thye used latex or something like that. But aside from that why do we use $\theta = 5$ and not $1$?
Not to mention how would someone go about solving alpha which is "the probability of rejecting the null when it's true"? So far I've only solved questioned with normal distribtion so I am a little confused here.

You are right. There is an error. The upper limit of integration must be $0.05$.
The power is defined by the formula $\inf_{\theta \in \Theta_1} \mathbb{E}_{X \sim \theta}[T(X)]$ for any test $T$. In this case, $\Theta_1 = \{5\}$, $T(x) = 0$ if $x \geqslant 0.05$ and $T(x) = 1$ otherwise. so you are computing $\mathbb{E}[T(X)]$ with $X$ following $\text{exp}(5)$ distribution.
